# Where is my contribution towards Ocean Week (2017) tracked?

Tags: league-of-legends

Riot, in reference to Ocean Week (2017), have a FAQ that states:

> How can I track my contribution?
>
> You’ll be able to see the total amount of points that you’ve individually contributed through the client.

But I've looked in a few places in the client and couldn't find where it is. Could someone more specifically state where it shows the contribution that I have made to Ocean Week?

Comment: Note to potention answerers: This is an OCE server exclusive. Please don't answer "this doesn't exist" nor "this is a scam". It's not, it's just OCE restricted.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your contribution on the [official site for the Ocean Week 2017](http://oce.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/oceanweek-2017).

Now this is on the web and unfortunately I can't 100% tell where you can see it in the client since I play on EUW, however from some comments I've seen it appears to be visible in the post-game screen. (Again not 100% sure).

[Image of the tracker on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4PcN.png)

Also keep in mind that you have to enlist in order to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was only in the old client since Ocean Week started, but it seems that the new client now has the Ocean Week Tracker.

The Ocean Week Tracker, including personal contributions, can be seen in the home page of the new client, under the *OCEAN WEEK 2017* tab.

[image]